# HTTPS on my ASP.NET 2.0 application

Tags: asp.net, https

I have an application developed using asp.net 2.0 and the goal is to make the webpage secure by using the https protocol.

I have searched all over the internet for some insight on how to accomplish this, and I have read about certificates, and so on, but couldn't quite figure this out yet.

So my question is, how can I accomplish this?

Explain this to me as if I didn't know anything about https.

I am using IIS 6.0 and ASP.NET 2.0.

Comment: To me this question sounds like: I don't want to invest time, please do it for me. If you _really_ do find nothing regarding HTTPS, see [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure).

Comment: fits better on serverfault.com

Comment: Don't know whether you host your website on your own server or not, but if you're using a hosting services out there, they should be able to help you install everything.

Answer (score 1):

Http over SSL - To accomplish this you will need a Signed Certificate. For a development purpose you can use Self Signed Certificate.

Here is an article on how to achieve this:

http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/creating_self_signed_certificates_iis

Once you have the certificate ready, you will have to map it to the website and you should be good to go.

On a Production System, if you are using a Shared Hosting, generally the Shared Hosting providers give you a folder location or ability to map folders for Https from Control Panel. For a VPN/Dedicated Server, you will get/purchase the certificate from a Signing Authority and do the same step of mapping it to the IIS server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The objective of the application is to be deployed on various servers when it's finished. Does this mean that i will need to have more than one certificate?

Comment: Then you are reffering a load balanced / Web Farm environment. Here are the instruction for how to set the environment up.. Also remember to mention this while getting the signed certificate from the certificate authority : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313299

Comment: What i quite don't understand is what the certificate does exactly.

Comment: What the certificate does is say that this server with this name, such as example.com is the server that was originally given the certificate. It's possible to fool a web browser that your fake server is example.com, but it's not possible for you to create a fake certificate.